# How does aws validates signatures created using access keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cryptography, aws-cli

I have searched a lot and all pages are talking about how to sign a request using aws access keys. But nowhere I am finding how aws validates those signatures.

For example, this official doc talks about various ways of authenticating yourself provided by aws. It talks about how aws uses public key of key pair to validate the signature.
But it talks nothing about how aws validates requests signed using access keys.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html

I find aws access keys very confusing. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Signing AWS API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html)

When you send a request to AWS, you send:

- API request with params etc.,
- Your access key (that begins with AK....)
- Signature that is generated using the corresponding `secret key` of your access key

AWS validates signature:

- Gets your secret key for the access key passed in the request
- Signs your request and compares it against the signature you supplied
- Makes sure the request is not replayed by MIM by checking the timestamp of the request is within 5 minutes of signing.

> To prevent tampering with a request while it's in transit, some of the
>   request elements are used to calculate a hash (digest) of the request,
>   and the resulting hash value is included as part of the request.
>   **When an AWS service receives the request, it uses the same information to calculate a hash and matches it against the hash value
>   in your request.** If the values don't match, AWS denies the request.

Comment: I had guessed so. But this part from your answer does not appear in any documentation - "Gets your secret key for the access key passed in the request". It's then like saying that, aws has knowledge of both access and secret access keys. It can then potentially misuse access kes and generate request on you behalf. This is unlike ec2 key pair, where instances are configured only with public key. The private part remains only with the user.

Comment: @ManojkumarKhotele of course AWS knows the access key and the corresponding secret key. But AWS doesn't know the private key of the EC2 keypair.

Comment: Thanks @helloV. I am accepting this answer. There cannot be any other way of validating the signature.